# mongodb: how to check if a value is associated to a specific key

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to write a python program that checks if a value is mapped to a specific key in a mongodb document. Is there anyway to do this?

```
if { key_1 : value_1 } in db_i/collection_j/document_k:
    do this
elif { key_1 : value_2 } in db_i/collection_j/document_k:
    do something else
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you want to do `if document.get('key1', None) == 'value_1'`?

Comment: I've never seen that code so I'm not sure. I'm basically checking if the key "Available" maps to True. If so, I will continue with my program. If { "Available" : False }, my program will print "Hardware is unavailable" and exit.

Comment: What is `db_i/collection_j/document_k`?

Comment: `for e in search_keys : if cursor[db][collection][document].find_one({key:e}) != None : #you got a found !`

Comment: db_i/collection_j/document_k refers to any database, collection and document of my choosing. I'm trying to determine if key : value pair {"Available" : "True"} exists within a certain document in my database @styvane

Comment: @dsgdfg I'm confused what your code is saying. is e the value I'm looking for? what does search_keys and cursor map to? and what does [document] do...there's no way to specify a document in mongodb without querying for key-value pairs that exist within that document

Comment: I think I figured it out, thanks @dsgdfg. Here's my code: if db.collection.find_one({"Pod": "24", "Available": False}) is None: perform update. Pod 24 is the document I'm updating (if Available = True). If it isn't available, no update is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer, thanks to the comments above:

```
if db.collection.find_one({"Pod":"24"},{"Available":False}) is None:
    perform update that "$sets" {"Available":False}
else:
    do nothing because {Available:False} already exists
    print "Pod 24 is already unavailable"
```

This allows me to check if the key-value pair exists in the query document (Pod 24) and do something (change Available to False) based on the result.